# find the number of permutations for no two identical elements sit next to each other

Tags: math, permutation

I need some help for this problem ive been facing
suppose I have an array=[3,4,1,5,6,1,3]

now I need the permutation that the duplicate element 3 should not sit beside other 3 and same for 1.
how am I suppose to solve this ive watched a ton of YouTube and googled it but no luck
for the help thanks in advance.,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a general case solution or just for that particular array? If you are looking for more general case, I think you should specify the restrictions or the problem becomes too complex. Same applies for if you want to write a code. Some languages (like Python) have libraries that makes these works relatively simple, but the time complexity can get ugly. 
Here's mathmatical approached to the problem:

**Step 1:** Suppose all the elements are different a = [3,4,5,6,1]
In this case we will have 5! different options (You have 5 options to choose the first element and 4 options to choose the second and so on)

**Step 2**: Suppose you have one repeated element a = [1,3,4,5,6,1]
In this case we have 6!/2! different options (6! comes from Step 1 and we divide it by 2! because if you switch the position of repeated element to itself the array does not chance).
Now you want to exclude options where repeated elements appear next to each other. The trick is to treat them as one element. So now we have a = [(1,1), 3, 4, 5, 6]. There 5! different options. We subtract this from total, that is 6!/2! - 5! will give you the answer.

**Step 3**: (your case) Two repeated elements a = [3,4,1,5,6,1,3]
We continue with the same logic. In total we have 7!/(2!x2!) options. From Step 2, if we want to exclude cases where 1 appear next to 1 then we will have to substract 6! from total. Also we have 3 that appears twice too. So, we will subtract another 6! from total. Unfortunately, we have subtracted some cases twice (can you guess which). If we find which cases we subtracted twice and add them we will get the answer.
The cases that we subtracted twice are when 1 comes after 1 at the same time 3 comes after 3, that is a = [(1,1),4,5,6,(3,3)]. We have subtracted those options for both one and three. There are 5! cases like that (can you guess why?).

To some it up get 7!/(2!x2!) - 2x6! + 5!.

If you are not looking for general solution those numbers are not big so you can write a bruteforce code (To save some time/space convert array to string).

I might have missed something in calculations but if you follow the logic you will get the answer. Also, if you want to understand why those things work try it with small data to get the intuition. If you need code, let me know. I will update the solution.